# Override collection view in UICollectionViewController

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I want to use my `CustomCollectionView` instead of the default `UICollectionView` used by `UICollectionViewController`. How can I override the type of the default property?

I take the [SimpleCollectionView example](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/SimpleCollectionView) as base. I tried this

```
public SimpleCollectionViewController (UICollectionViewLayout layout) : base (layout)
{
    CollectionView = new CustomCollectionView (View.Frame, layout);
    // ...
}
```

but it crashes, because the `AnimalCell` has not been registered. Then I tried

```
public override CustomCollectionView CollectionView {
    get;
    set;
}
```

but it doesn't compile because the overriden member is of type `UICollectionView`.

How can I override the default `UICollectionView`, while preserving memory managment, layout, position, size and so on?

**Edit:**

Now I tried to use the following getter/setter:

```
public new CustomCollectionView CollectionView {
    get {
        if (CollectionView == null) {
            CollectionView = new CustomCollectionView ();
        }
        return CollectionView;
    }
    set {
        CollectionView = value;
    }
}
```

This is my constructor:

```
public SimpleCollectionViewController (UICollectionViewLayout layout) : base (layout)
{
    CollectionView = new CustomCollectionView (View.Frame, layout);
    // ...
}
```

Then I wanted to use the following constructor in my `CustomCollectionView` class:

```
public CustomCollectionView() : base()
{
}
```

But that isn't allowed as can be seen in the [available constructors](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UICollectionView/#Public_Constructors). I don't know which constructor is appropriate. The only one which makes sense for me leads to a stack overflow when using this

```
public new CustomCollectionView CollectionView {
    get {
        if (CollectionView == null) {
            CollectionView = new CustomCollectionView (View.Frame, Layout);
        }
        return CollectionView;
        }
    set {
        CollectionView = value;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Now I tried this property declaration

```
private CustomCollectionView _collectionView;
public new CustomCollectionView CollectionView {
    get {
        if (_collectionView == null) {
            _collectionView = new CustomCollectionView (View.Frame, new UICollectionViewFlowLayout());
        }
        return _collectionView;
    }
    set {
        _collectionView = value;
    }
}
```

and in the constructor of `SimpleCollectionViewController` I do this

```
CollectionView = new CustomCollectionView (View.Frame, layout);
```

Again it doesn't work (crashes), because the header wasn't correctly registered, when trying to dequeue it at

```
var headerView = (Header)collectionView.DequeueReusableSupplementaryView (elementKind, headerId, indexPath);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there an explanation why you voted -1? Perhaps I can improve and edit my question. If you think the question is too easy for you, you could leave an answer. The `UICollectionViewController` is a convenient class and I want to exchange the type of one property without creating a new one and duplicating things.

Comment: I could also use a normal `UIViewController` and add everything there, but I ask if there is a way to use the convenient class, because memory management is handled for me there.